# Node.js Unable to load the webpage The connection has timed out

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, webserver

I'm a beginner to node.js, I installed it as here:
`https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager`

I tried it from console and it worked:

`console.log('Hello World!');`

`nodejs helloConsole.js`

`> Hello World!`

Then I tried to make it within HTTP Server, here is the code:

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   request.on("end", function () {
      response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      response.end('Hello HTTP!');
   });
}).listen(8080);
```

I run it from terminal:

`nodejs hello.js`

then I open the browser at `http://localhost:8080/` , it takes a long time to load, then at chrome it gives me that:

`Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.`

and firefox gives me that:

`The connection has timed out`

Note : other web servers works fine, like apache.

Comment: that exact code copy pasted works on my machine... how strange. did the process continue to run after `node hello.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are listening to the "end" event of the request parameter, but at the time your outermost callback function is called, the request has already ended, so it is too late to subscribe to that event.

You can directly respond from the outermost callback, which is what the sample code in nodejs.org shows.

Comment: I got that code from: `http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/` I'm wondering why they use it in the tutorial with this mistake !!

Comment: It's a bit outdated, one year is a looong time ;D

Answer (score 2):

You attached a listener to the `request` object, listening for the `end` event, you will not see a response until that event has been caught by `request`.

To test things out you might want to modify it like the one provided as example here: http://nodejs.org/

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: What does that mean "until that event has been caught by request." ??

Comment: doesn't the request end by opening the requested page?

Comment: Look at Luis answer for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps, if you are using windows, it may help you.

1. Download the `node.exe` from http://nodejs.org/download/
2. Place in a `Hard Disk Drive` from where you want to run like `D:/nodejs/node.exe`
3. Now place your `hello.js` in the same `directory` it should look like `D:/nodejs/hello.js`
4. Now from `Command Prompt` Go to that folder `D:/nodejs/` and run command `node hello.js`